# Swift: How to compare two Dictionary<String, Any> structs?

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I'm using the [`Static`](https://github.com/venmo/Static) framework written in Swift that uses `typealias Context = [String: Any]` for storing additional information for a row.

Now, I need to compare if two `Context` structs are equal in an `extension Row`:

```
public func ==(lhs: Row, rhs: Row) -> Bool {
    // TODO: image, ...
    return lhs.text == rhs.text
        && lhs.detailText == rhs.detailText
        && lhs.accessory == rhs.accessory
        && lhs.context == rhs.context
}
```

So I implement the `==` operator for `Row.Context`:

```
public func ==(lhs: Row.Context, rhs: Row.Context) -> Bool {
    return Array(lhs.keys) == Array(rhs.keys)
    // TODO: && Array(lhs.values) == Array(rhs.values)
}
```

but now, in order to `lhs.context == rhs.context` I need to extend the `Row.Context` type to conform to `Equatable`:

```
extension Row.Context: Equatable {}
```

Which is exactly where I'm stuck with the following error:

> "Constrained extension must be declared on the unspecialized generic
>   type 'Dictionary' with constraints specified by a 'where' clause"

[image: error - extension Row.Context: Equatable]

Ignoring the implementation of `func ==` for Row.Context for now, **how to make `Row.Context` conform to `Equatable`?**

Comment: `Any` isn't `Equatable`, so you cannot possibly define an equality operator for two dictionaries where the values are `Any` – as you have no way of comparing those values with each other (there's already a standard library equality operator for dictionaries where the values are `Equatable`). You'd have to limit the values of your dictionary to a concrete type that's `Equatable`.