# Swift 3.0 binary operator '==' cannot be applied

Tags: swift, swift3

In Swift 3.0 I'm getting a weird error when I try to compare two items which are of type `[[String: AnyObject]]` and `[[String: AnyObject]]!`. So one of them is force unwrapped and the other is not.

So the comparison looks like:

```
let smth: [[String: AnyObject]] = [["key": "Value"]]
let smth2: [[String: AnyObject]]?  = someFunctionThatReturnsAnOptionalArrayOfDictionaries()

if smth == smth2! {
    print("Equal")
}
```

The error says: `Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type '[[String : AnyObject]]' and '[[String : AnyObject]]!'`

What is the correct way to do this in Swift 3?

Comment: Can you specify the weird error?

Comment: Added, sorry for that.

Comment: What Xcode are you using?

Comment: Version 8.0 (8A218a)

Comment: Any isn't equatable. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38352402/swift-how-to-compare-two-dictionarystring-any-structs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a little tricky, since you can't directly compare arrays or dictionaries (without overloading operators).

Another problem you could be facing is optional and non-optional comparisons, which was removed in Swift 3 (**only for `<` and `>`, `==` and  `!=` still work!**):

**[Swift Evolution - Proposal #0121](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0121-remove-optional-comparison-operators.md#impact-on-existing-code)**

What I did to make it work was first unwrap the optional with `if let` then I compared them with `elementsEqual`, first the array, then the dictionary.

```
let smth: [[String: AnyObject]] = [["key": "Value" as AnyObject]]
let smth2: [[String: AnyObject]]?  = nil

if let smth2 = smth2, smth.elementsEqual(smth2, by: { (obj1, obj2) -> Bool in
    return obj1.elementsEqual(obj2) { (elt1, elt2) -> Bool in
        return elt1.key == elt2.key && elt1.value === elt2.value
    }

}) {
    print("Equal")
}
```

Another problem is, since you are using `AnyObject` as value, you can't compare them directly. Thats why I used `===` which checks if the reference of comparing objects is the same. Not sure if this is what you wanted.

Comment: Wow.. just wow. This introduces a crapload of code for something as simple as comparing two JSON objects converted into swift objects. But I guess I don't really have a choice.

Comment: Exactly. Maybe you'd had it simple with comparing JSON Strings?

Comment: Nah, things get converted as soon as I get a response from the API and this is some logic in one of the controllers. Serializing it back into JSON strings would just be wasting performance all over the place.

Comment: That proposal is about `<` etc comparisons. It explicitly mentions that Variants of `==` and `!=` which accept optional operands are not changed in Swift 3.

Comment: Oh my bad then! Thanks! But this still doesn't change the code, since for `elementsEqual`the arrays still need to be unwrapped.

Answer (score 2):

[This SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32366918/2466193) answer includes a solution to this problem under the sub-heading 'Xcode 8 beta 6 • Swift 3'.

Note in particular:

> In the example above all dictionary keys and values are the same type. If we try to compare two dictionaries of type [String: Any] Xcode will complain that Binary operator == cannot be applied to two [String: Any] operands. ... But we can extend the == operator functionality using the NSDictionary initializer:

Comment: Wow.. how lame :) What is the best way to do this now? I'm only using `[[String: AnyObject]]` types for arrays of JSON objects returned from APIs. Objects always have either a string or a number or something like that as a value. Any ideas?

Comment: How about [the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32365828/2466193) to that same question, I.e. Use NSObject instead of AnyObject?