# Binary operators with Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

I am switching to Swift 3 and i am getting following compiler error for this line:

```
    if cma.socket.status != .Connected {
        cma.socket.connect()
        print("connect");
    }else{
        cma.socket.reconnect()
        print("reconnect")
    }
```

> Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   'SocketIOClientStatus' and '_'

I found this question: [Swift 3.0 binary operator '==' cannot be applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39567886/swift-3-0-binary-operator-cannot-be-applied) but still don't know how to fix it.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Have you double checked that the case you're comparing is still called `.Connected`?

Comment: Voting to close this question as a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The enum is defined as:

```
@objc public enum SocketIOClientStatus : Int {
    case notConnected, disconnected, connecting, connected
}
```

This means your code needs a small change (pun intended):

```
if cm.socket.status != .connected {
```

Comment: Wow, that fixed :) But i have one more error like this. Could you check? http://prntscr.com/ctxu0z